# How to click any available seat in Redbus.in?(see attached screenshot for UI details)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: UI of the View Seats page]

[image]

Is there any way to click the available seats in Redbus.in. Below is the navigation steps:

1. Open URL https://www.redbus.in
2. Enter Source and Destination and travel date
3. List of bus operator will be displayed in which select any "View Seats" button.

DOM details for that particular section:

```
<canvas data-type="upper" width="383" height="193" class=""></canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Either a deeplink to the exact website or at least a proper Source, Destination, Travel Date and the Bus Operator.

Or provide a bigger section of the DOM, because that particular section you posted has no unique selector.

Comment: Please try to enter this url direct in address bar: http://www.redbus.in/search?fromCityName=Bangalore&fromCityId=122&toCityName=Goa&toCityId=210&onward=26-Feb-2017&opId=0&busType=Any

Comment: After that click on any "View Seats" button and select any available seats. That UI will look like above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way this website is written, it is nigh impossible to specifically select a certain seat as you cannot create a `css-selector` or `xpath` to find an element within a `<canvas>`.

The only possibility you might have is using `Actions` to move your mouse to a (more or less) exact position on the canvas.

[Here is a blog post](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/) that could help you.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Is there any java script or some scripting which is triggered when we click any particular seat? I was not able to find any event when we hover mouse between those seats.

Comment: No, I'm sorry I can't help you with that. It would be the best to get in contact with the developers of that website (if you can) and talk to them to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to take automated step to book tickets? Is it for any commercial purpose? If yes, then you can check their **API** branded as Seat Seller. Here is the [doc](http://api.seatseller.travel/docs/).

Otherwise you would need screen offset of the seats and need to fire demo mouse event to click those items, as this is an canvas. Same thing with google maps.